# Is there an algorithm to identify the most salient word from a given set of words?

Tags: cpu-word, similarity, wordnet

I'm trying to find out the importance of a word from a given set of random words. For instance, I would like to know that "accident" is the most important word from the words "man, woman, accident". A naive solution was to get a WordNet depth for each word and calculate an importance of the word based on the dissimilarity in the word depths. This solution is quite time consuming since this requires n(n-1) calculations to generate the final importance. Is there a better solution to handle this scenario?

Comment: How is this related to python?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I'm using nltk and python with my current implementation. I'll edit the qn. right away.

Comment: Do you have a proper definition for "importance"?  If it's related to information content, maybe you could simply use frequency counts from a corpus (frequently used words tend to be less specific).

Comment: Like I said in the question, importance is from the set of words. I'm not using a paragraph or sentence but just a few words that are provided. Another example I could give is, "man,walk,shot" wherein "shot" turns up as the most important from the set of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is that the less common a word is, the more important it is.

First, choose a corpus that represents your problem domain. Then run a word frequency count over it. You could skip these two sets and use a pre-made list, e.g. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists and e.g. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/PG/2006/04/1-10000  However, making word frequencies is one of the easier things to do in Python/NLTK.

The third step is to find the frequency of each of your input words, and the one with the *lowest* frequency is the most salient. Or, if this is input to another step and a real number is useful, [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) gives you that.

You might want to normalize/stem words first. That will depend on your application. But, if you do, make sure you do it both in the generation stage (i.e. normalize your corpus), and in the usage stage (normalize your inputs).

Here are some examples, using frequency counts from the Word Usage Trends box here at http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/man:

```
man          0.0289
woman        0.0149
walk         0.0064
shot         0.0049
accident     0.0048
```

Luckily those numbers match up with the correct answers you gave: accident and shot.

Comment: Thanks for providing a good way to tackle this problem. I was initially using the inverse of the frequency count across all the lemmas to find the word saliency. Stemming did come across my mind but NLTK or any word engine does pretty bad stemming.